# Docusign custom field in envelope not showing up in callback

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending this envelope to docusign:

```
{
 "status":"sent",
 "emailSubject":"Please work.",
 "recipients":
   {
   "signers":[
     {
     "name":"me",
     "email":"myemail@yahoo.com",
     "recipientId":"1",
     "tabs":
       {
       "signHereTabs":[
         {
         "xPosition":25,
         "yPosition":25,
         "documentId":1,
         "pageNumber":1
         }
       ]
       }
     },
     {
      "name":"Joe Smith",
      "email":"js@yahoo.com",
      "recipientId":"2",
      "tabs":
        {
        "signHereTabs":[
          {
          "xPosition":125,
          "yPosition":125,
          "documentId":1,
          "pageNumber":1
          }
        ]
        }
      }
    ]
    },
  "applicationId":"2",
  "documents":[
    {
    "documentId":1,
    "documentBase64":"blahblah"
    }
  }
}
```

This is all working fine, (Sending docs, signing, callback..) As you can see,  I have a custom attribute, "applicationId" in the envelope.

In my docusign admin console under Envelope Custom Fields, I have added applicationId as required text.

When I analyze the XML from the callback from Docusign in my app,  I see this:

```
 <CustomField><Name>applicationId</Name><Show>True</Show><Required>True</Required><Value /></CustomField>
```

Why is this coming back blank? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom fields need to be specified within a `customFields` object in the API request (where `customFields` is top-level property in the JSON request body, i.e., a peer of the `documents` property).

---

**UPDATE** (corrected format of `customFields` object)

This is how you need to format the contents of the `customFields` object in the API request (assuming that the custom field you're specifying is a text custom field):

```
"customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
        {
            "name": "applicationId",
            "value": "2"
        }       
    ]
}
```

Comment: That did not work.  I did this:  {"status":"sent","emailSubject":"Please sign this.","customFields":{"applicationId":"16483"}  But the XML coming back still has a blank applicationId.   I can even see it in the logs on the Docusign Admin Console

Comment: Sorry about that -- I've updated my answer with a revised JSON snippet that shows the correct format for the customFields object.